# Text Input and Image Firefox Alignment Issue

Tags: css, firefox, textbox, alignment

I am pulling me hair out about this one.
http://www.nettunes.co.za/build/contact.php

I have an image at the end of a text input that is styled with a background image, here is the css:
`.text_input{
    background:url(../images/forms/text_input_back.png) top left no-repeat;
    width:479px;
    border-style:none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#cacaca;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    padding-left:15px;
}`

In all browsers except firefox, the alignment is fine. In firefox the image at the end of the text input is 1px too low.

Any help here would be massively appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `padding-top` and `padding:bottom` from `.text_input` and use `height:45px;` instead

Comment: I dont have enough reputation :)